# Custom AWS IAM Identity Service logo or UI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Recently I managed to make an SSO/SAML integration between Adobe Sign and AWS IAM Identity Center (Formerly AWS SSO), now, when signing in users are redirected to AWS and are prompted to input user and password.

However, I have not been able to customize the sign in page, not even changing the logo. **My question is: is there a way to at least change the IAM Identity Center Logo?** (A plus if I could customize the whole UI)

Thanks in advance!